# Dynamically add javascript code

Tags: php, jquery, load

I have some third party javascript code

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" SRC="http://some-videos.com/addbutton.cfm?ID=20415454598212"></SCRIPT>
```

When this code is added in html file it shows one play button, now i want that if user clicks on any button one function should be called and that function will load this js code. I have tried .load, .getScript, .ajax but nothing is working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
    function loadVideo()
    {
       $('#videoButton').load("http://some-videos.com/addbutton.cfm?ID=20415454598212");
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="videoButton"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Load Video Button" onclick="loadVideo();" />
    <br /><br />
    Below code shows one play button, that is generated through included javascript file.
    <SCRIPT language="JavaScript" SRC="http://some-videos.com/addbutton.cfm?ID=20415454598212"></SCRIPT>
    <!-- I have added dummy Url -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: error, how ur calling ...little more specific plz :)

Comment: `$.getScript` is exactly what you are looking for. Could you please provide an example of what you have tried with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction()
{
    $('head').append($('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://some-videos.com/addbutton.cfm?ID=20415454598212"></script>'));    
}
```

I suppose using jQuery. This way will be external Javascript loaded on demand.

Comment: Use `head` instead of `header` ;)

Comment: Not working, it is something like adverting js script when we add such a script on our website it outputs something.